# Converting regular expression to NFA.

Tags: regular-expressions

I have the following two regular expressions and I need to convert them to NFA diagrams. I already did some and was wondering if they made any sense...i hope I'm not confusing the signs.

```
e+ a(a + b)* + (a + b)*aa(a + b)*
```

[image]

```
[ba+(a+bb)a*b]*
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, which is very important, is that automata are always denoted by *directed* graphs. So do draw arcs (with arrow) instead of undirected edges. Be careful while you correct it.

Apart from that, your diagrams are *almost* correct except for the second, just before the self loop. Those two $a$'s should be $\epsilon$'s.

Comment: Yeah I saw that too. And of course they are directed, this was just a rough sketch. Thanks for the help.